# Why are most of the mirrors for the Arch repositories dead?

Tags: arch-linux, repository, mirror

Most of the mirrors are dead:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.aktkn.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.aktkn.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from download.nus.edu.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from sgp.mirror.pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.nus.edu.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.acm.wpi.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'llvm-libs-8.0.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.advancedhosters.com : The requested URL returned error: 40
.
.
.
```

When I first installed Arch I used only one of them, i.e. `Server = http://mirror.xeonbd.com/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch`. Now I've to keep all of them in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` to find package from a valid repository! Almost all of them now returns `404`!

Anything wrong with Arch?

---

**EDIT**

This site said `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 35758.` So I'd to take out some error lines in the middle and end and replaced those with three vertical dots:

```
[emon@haque ~]$ ssh root@192.168.0.104
root@192.168.0.104's password: 
Last login: Thu Aug 29 23:09:47 2019 from 192.168.0.103
root@archiso ~ # mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
root@archiso ~ # mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
mke2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
/dev/sda2 contains a ext4 file system
        last mounted on Thu Aug 29 23:11:04 2019
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 78643200 4k blocks and 19660800 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 7d60994f-e3fb-47d9-9735-6e6e0b42f83b
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done     

root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
root@archiso ~ # timedatectl set-ntp true
root@archiso ~ # pacstrap /mnt base
==> Creating install root at /mnt
==> Installing packages to /mnt
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                                                                           132.3 KiB  3.00M/s 00:00 [##############################################################] 100%
 extra                                                                         1651.1 KiB  4.39M/s 00:00 [##############################################################] 100%
 community                                                                        4.9 MiB  3.59M/s 00:01 [##############################################################] 100%
:: There are 50 members in group base:
:: Repository core
   1) bash  2) bzip2  3) coreutils  4) cryptsetup  5) device-mapper  6) dhcpcd  7) diffutils  8) e2fsprogs  9) file  10) filesystem  11) findutils  12) gawk  13) gcc-libs
   14) gettext  15) glibc  16) grep  17) gzip  18) inetutils  19) iproute2  20) iputils  21) jfsutils  22) less  23) licenses  24) linux  25) linux-firmware  26) logrotate
   27) lvm2  28) man-db  29) man-pages  30) mdadm  31) nano  32) netctl  33) pacman  34) pciutils  35) perl  36) procps-ng  37) psmisc  38) reiserfsprogs  39) s-nail
   40) sed  41) shadow  42) sysfsutils  43) systemd-sysvcompat  44) tar  45) texinfo  46) usbutils  47) util-linux  48) vi  49) which  50) xfsprogs

Enter a selection (default=all): 
resolving dependencies...
:: There are 2 providers available for resolvconf:
:: Repository core
   1) openresolv  2) systemd-resolvconf

Enter a number (default=1): 
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (138) acl-2.2.53-1  archlinux-keyring-20190805-1  argon2-20190702-1  attr-2.4.48-1  audit-2.8.5-3  ca-certificates-20181109-1  ca-certificates-mozilla-3.45-1
               ca-certificates-utils-20181109-1  cracklib-2.9.7-1  curl-7.65.3-1  db-5.3.28-4  dbus-1.12.16-2  expat-2.2.7-1  gdbm-1.18.1-2  glib2-2.60.6-1  gmp-6.1.2-2
               gnupg-2.2.17-2  gnutls-3.6.9-1  gpgme-1.13.1-1  groff-1.22.4-1  hwids-20190316-1  iana-etc-20190722-1  icu-64.2-1  iptables-1:1.8.3-1  json-c-0.13.1-2
               kbd-2.0.4-2  keyutils-1.6.1-1  kmod-26-2  krb5-1.17-1  libaio-0.3.112-1  libarchive-3.4.0-2  libassuan-2.5.3-1  libcap-2.27-1  libcap-ng-0.7.9-1
               libcroco-0.6.13-1  libelf-0.176-1  libffi-3.2.1-3  libgcrypt-1.8.4-1  libgpg-error-1.36-1  libidn2-2.2.0-1  libksba-1.3.5-1  libldap-2.4.47-3  libmnl-1.0.4-2
               libnetfilter_conntrack-1.0.7-1  libnfnetlink-1.0.1-3  libnftnl-1.1.3-1  libnghttp2-1.39.1-1  libnl-3.4.0-1  libpcap-1.9.0-1  libpipeline-1.5.1-1
               libpsl-0.21.0-1  libsasl-2.1.27-1  libseccomp-2.4.1-2  libsecret-0.18.8-2  libssh2-1.8.2-1  libtasn1-4.14-1  libtirpc-1.1.4-1  libunistring-0.9.10-1
               libusb-1.0.22-1  libutil-linux-2.34-3  libxml2-2.9.9-2  linux-api-headers-5.1-1  lz4-1:1.9.1-1  mkinitcpio-25-2  mkinitcpio-busybox-1.30.1-1  mpfr-4.0.2-1
               ncurses-6.1-6  nettle-3.5.1-1  npth-1.6-1  openresolv-3.9.1-1  openssl-1.1.1.c-1  p11-kit-0.23.16.1-1  pacman-mirrorlist-20190821-1  pam-1.3.1-1
               pambase-20190105.1-1  pcre-8.43-1  pcre2-10.33-1  pinentry-1.1.0-4  popt-1.16-10  readline-8.0.0-1  sqlite-3.29.0-1  systemd-242.84-2  systemd-libs-242.84-2
               thin-provisioning-tools-0.8.5-2  tzdata-2019b-1  xz-5.2.4-1  zlib-1:1.2.11-3  zstd-1.4.2-1  bash-5.0.007-1  bzip2-1.0.8-2  coreutils-8.31-1
               cryptsetup-2.2.0-1  device-mapper-2.02.185-1  dhcpcd-7.2.2-1  diffutils-3.7-1  e2fsprogs-1.45.3-1  file-5.37-2  filesystem-2019.05-2  findutils-4.6.0-4
               gawk-4.2.1-2  gcc-libs-9.1.0-2  gettext-0.19.8.1-3  glibc-2.29-4  grep-3.3-1  gzip-1.10-1  inetutils-1.9.4-7  iproute2-5.2.0-1  iputils-20180629.f6aac8d-4
               jfsutils-1.1.15-6  less-551-1  licenses-20181104-1  linux-5.2.9.arch1-1  linux-firmware-20190815.07b925b-1  logrotate-3.15.0-1  lvm2-2.02.185-1
               man-db-2.8.6.1-1  man-pages-5.02-1  mdadm-4.1-1  nano-4.3-1  netctl-1.20-1  pacman-5.1.3-1  pciutils-3.6.2-1  perl-5.30.0-3  procps-ng-3.3.15-1  psmisc-23.2-1
               reiserfsprogs-3.6.27-2  s-nail-14.9.14-1  sed-4.7-1  shadow-4.7-2  sysfsutils-2.1.0-10  systemd-sysvcompat-242.84-2  tar-1.32-1  texinfo-6.6-1  usbutils-010-1
               util-linux-2.34-3  vi-1:070224-3  which-2.21-3  xfsprogs-4.20.0-2

Total Download Size:    278.54 MiB
Total Installed Size:  1090.91 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 linux-api-headers-5.1-1-any                                                    981.8 KiB  5.21M/s 00:00 [##############################################################] 100%
 tzdata-2019b-1-x86_64                                                          340.9 KiB  5.84M/s 00:00 [##############################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.lastmikoi.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu : Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.snt.utwente.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.uta.edu.ec : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.librelabucm.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.nav.ro : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from gluttony.sin.cvut.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.ufam.edu.br : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.puzzle.ch : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from za.mirror.archlinux-br.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.kernel.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.bytemark.co.uk : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.advancedhosters.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.sadjad.ac.ir : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.host.ag : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.za.mirror.allworldit.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.ba : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.internode.on.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.netix.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.selfnet.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from shadow.ind.ntou.edu.tw : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.yzu.edu.tw : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.cat.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archmirror.lavatech.top : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.pcextreme.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.dynamict.se : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.pop-es.rnp.br : Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.gwdg.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.poliwangi.ac.id : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.jaist.ac.jp : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirrors.pair.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirrors.ovh.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.m247.ro : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de : Failed to connect to ftp.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de port 80: No route to host
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.fau.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.neuf.no : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.constant.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.gigenet.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.udenar.edu.co : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.harukasan.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.rafal.ca : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www.gutscheindrache.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.kku.ac.th : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.arnoldthebat.co.uk : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.garr.it : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.sh.cvut.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.reisenbauer.ee : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.i3d.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.c3sl.ufpr.br : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.koyanet.lv : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.tku.edu.tw : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.uni-bayreuth.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.miserver.it.umich.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.lug.mtu.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.petarmaric.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.mirror.colo-serv.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archimonde.ts.si : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.nluug.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.nxthost.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.osuosl.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.rackspace.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.mikrogravitation.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.checkdomain.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.cs.pitt.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.wdc1.us.leaseweb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from suro.ubaya.ac.id : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.nic.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xtom.com.hk : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.easyname.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.premi.st : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.isoc.org.il : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.koddos.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.cedille.club : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.smith.geek.nz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.neostrada.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.one.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.celianvdb.fr : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.aktkn.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.atviras.lt : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ca.us.mirror.archlinux-br.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from iad.mirrors.misaka.one : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.ubrco.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archmirror.hbit.sztaki.hu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mir.archlinux.fr : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.truenetwork.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.linux.cz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.math.princeton.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.n-ix.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.system.is : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.lzu.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.wrz.de : Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.united-gameserver.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.dal10.us.leaseweb.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from linux.rz.rub.de : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from tux.rainside.sk : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.163.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.ufro.cl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.zju.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from distro.ibiblio.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.fsmg.org.nz : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.metrocast.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.adct.be : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.surlyjake.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from glua.ua.pt : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.rol.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.honkgong.info : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.vtti.vt.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www.caco.ic.unicamp.br : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.rediris.es : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.cc.uoc.gr : The requested URL returned error: 404
.
.
.
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.cqu.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
 iana-etc-20190722-1-any                                                           368.1 KiB   224K/s 00:02 [################################################################] 100%
 filesystem-2019.05-2-x86_64                                                        27.8 KiB  4.53M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 glibc-2.29-4-x86_64                                                                 9.1 MiB  3.43M/s 00:03 [################################################################] 100%
 gcc-libs-9.1.0-2-x86_64                                                            22.7 MiB  3.49M/s 00:06 [################################################################] 100%
 ncurses-6.1-6-x86_64                                                             1066.4 KiB  4.12M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 readline-8.0.0-1-x86_64                                                           296.1 KiB  4.82M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.lastmikoi.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
.
.
.
```

---

**EDIT**

Ths time I've chosen only Bangladesh and United States from [here](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/) to install, looks like some of US servers are dead too!

```
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 linux-api-headers-5.1-1-any                                                       981.8 KiB  5.24M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 tzdata-2019b-1-x86_64                                                             340.9 KiB  7.08M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.acm.wpi.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'iana-etc-20190722-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.advancedhosters.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
 iana-etc-20190722-1-any                                                           368.1 KiB   133K/s 00:03 [################################################################] 100%
 filesystem-2019.05-2-x86_64                                                        27.8 KiB  2.72M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 glibc-2.29-4-x86_64                                                                 9.1 MiB  3.50M/s 00:03 [################################################################] 100%
 gcc-libs-9.1.0-2-x86_64                                                            22.7 MiB  3.46M/s 00:07 [################################################################] 100%
 ncurses-6.1-6-x86_64                                                             1066.4 KiB  4.12M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
 readline-8.0.0-1-x86_64                                                           296.1 KiB  3.21M/s 00:00 [################################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.acm.wpi.edu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'bash-5.0.007-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.advancedhosters.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
```

Comment: What is the precise command you are running? Have you read [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors) about mirrors? There's a link there to the [mirror status](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/status/) page, which shows that mirror.xeonbd.com is out of date.

Comment: I was installing arch using `archlinux-2019.08.01-x86_64.iso`

Comment: You answered none of my questions.

Comment: @Sparhawk, got your answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. You [could try](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/8hoyn8/pacman_mirrors_return_404_when_installing_arch/dylf3lq/) `reflector`?

Comment: @Sparhawk, In some cases it actually retrives packages from `xeonbd`.

Answer (score 3):

The Arch Linux mirror repositories frequently delete packages that aren't the most recent version. Arch doesn't support partial system upgrades either, so to be explicit, you want:

```
pacman -Syu
```

to update everything including a list of available packages and version, then:

```
pacman -S <package>
```

Comment: It's during Arch Installation and I'm using latest `archlinux-2019.08.01-x86_64.iso`

Comment: That's expected. The iso itself is updated much less frequently than the mirrors, so you'll still have to sync and update the package lists on a new install

Comment: Now look at the edited part. I Just put the `xeonbd` at the top in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

Comment: does `pacman -Syu` work on installation media, i.e. live usb?

Comment: It should (maybe without `-u`), assuming `/var` is mounted read-write, but `pacstrap` _should_ be using the `-y` option internally already. Are there any packages that actually fail to install?

Comment: Yes, many of them, for example `error: failed retrieving file 'libreoffice-still-6.2.6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xeonbd.com : The requested URL returned error: 404`! I did a `pacman -Syu` on live usb but it produced a bunch of write errors at the end and during update I got exact same `404` errors!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to update keys first:

```
sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring
sudo pacman -Syu
```